# React --> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting this warning in browser console:

```
warning.js?da67:33 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
```

on line:

```
<p>{this.state.error && <p className="errorText">{this.state.error}</p>}</p>
```

It's a react project. Also I'm using webpack. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The warning tells you what exactly you need to do. You cannot nest `<p>` tags and hence use `div` for the outer tag like

```
<div>
   {this.state.error && 
      <p className="errorText">
           {this.state.error}
       </p>
   }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this and I getting another error, but now it's working :D

Comment: As per the spec you shouldn't be able to, but I don't know of any modern browser that won't render such a DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that issue by removing my parent  tag from my text fields